# How do I remove blank pages coming between two chapters in Appendix?

Tags: latex

Is there a way to remove blank pages appearing between two chapters, in Appendix?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Your problem is that all chapters, whether they're in the appendix or not, default to starting on an odd-numbered page when you're in two-sided layout mode. A few possible solutions:

The simplest solution is to use the `openany` option to your document class, which makes chapters start on the next page, irrespective of whether it's an odd or even numbered page. This is supported in the standard book documentclass, eg `\documentclass[openany]{book}`. ([`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) also supports using this as a declaration `\openany` which can be used in the middle of a document to change the behavior for subsequent pages.)

Another option is to try the `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` command before your appendices to avoid the behavior.

Or, if you don't care using a two-sided layout, using the option `oneside` to your `documentclass` (eg `\documentclass[oneside]{book}`) will switch to using a one-sided layout.

Comment: Your definition would remove ALL page breaks.  \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage would probably be more on target.

Comment: What documentclass are you using?

Comment: I tried with `book` and `scrbook`, but it works only if you put the command in the preamble.

Comment: I put \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage after \appendix and it works perfectly with book as documentclass. Thanks!

Comment: I need the twoside layout for my setup, but I dont want all the blank pages. The openany approach worked like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: Same as @OptimusCrime here, `openany` was the perfect solution for a thesis (document class that is based on "report" style).

Answer (score 99):

it is very easy:

add `\documentclass[oneside]{book}`
and youre fine ;)

Comment: @frederic: Truly Brilliant Solution. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Note that this method make the margins of all the pages the same. In twoside, the margins are different for the odd and the even pages.

Comment: As phaedrus mentioned, if you're printing a thesis, you usually need different left/right margins, for which you need to use the twosided option.

Comment: thanks, in my case

replacing `\documentclass[report,12pt]{memoir}`
with `\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}` helped

Comment: In addition to issue mentioned by phaedrus, ``oneside`` option also causes ``fancyhdr`` to ignore setup for even pages resulting in errors like this: ``Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is useless on input line 6791``. So ``openany`` option is much better in this case as it only affects location of each new chapter, instead of affecting margins and alternating headers/footers.

Comment: AWESOME! was looking for it

Answer (score 29):

I tried Noah's suggestion which leads to the best solution up to now.

Just insert `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` before all the parts with the blank pages
Especially when you use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}`

frederic snyers's advice `\documentclass[oneside]{book}` is also very good and solves the problem, but if we just want to use the book.cls or article.cls, the one would make a big difference presenting your particles.

Hence, Big support to `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` for the people who will ask the same question in the future.

Comment: where should I insert \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage? for example befor the \include{chapter2} in main.tex?

Comment: just put into the space where you want to delete the blank page, for instance, the blank page in certain chapter, you could try to put after \begin{document}

Comment: It worked perfectly for me inside \begin{document} and just before \tableofcontents. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

If you specify the option 'openany' in the \documentclass declaration each chapter in the book (I'm guessing you're using the book class as chapters open on the next page in reports and articles don't have chapters) will open on a new page, not necessarily the next odd-numbered page.

Of course, that's not quite what you want.  I think you want to set openany for chapters in the appendix.  'fraid I don't know how to do that, I suspect that you need to roll up your sleeves and wrestle with TeX itself

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I still wanted the open on odd pages option but this would produce a blank page with the chapter name in the header. I didn't want the header. And so to avoid this I used this at the end of the chapter:

```
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain}
```

This let's you keep the blank page on the last even page of the chapter but without the header.

Comment: This was quite helpful

Answer (score 3):

I put the `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` before `\makeindex`. Else, your content page will display page number based on the page number before you clear the blank page.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I discovered is that using the \include command will often insert and extra blank page. Riffing on the previous trick with the \let command, I inserted \let\include\input near the beginning of the document, and that got rid of most of the excessive blank pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. None of the previous methods worked for me. I replaced \include with \input , and it worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me also - using a slightly modified Koma Script report class. Any idea  why \include does this? How to debug the precise issue?

Comment: -1 I'd think it might make the most sense to just use `\input` if that's what you need, rather than redefining `\include` to be it. I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include#250 explains why this happens. It's because `\include` is intended to do more than just copy-paste text into the document.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `\openany`, `\openright` and `\openleft` commands:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\openany
\appendix

\openright
\appendixpage
This is the appendix.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have these commands :-(

Answer (score 0):

To remove blank pages between two chapters in the Appendix when using LaTeX, you can consider the following approaches:

1. Remove Page Breaks Manually:

Open your LaTeX document.
Navigate to the location where a blank page appears between two chapters in the Appendix.
Add the command \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage just before the problematic section or chapter.
This command essentially changes the behavior of \cleardoublepage to act like \clearpage, preventing LaTeX from inserting an empty page.
latex

```
\documentclass{your_document_class}

\begin{document}

% Your document content here

\appendix

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage % Add this line to prevent blank pages in the Appendix

% Appendix content here

\end{document}
```

2. Modify Document Class Options:
   Check if your document class has options related to page breaks and chapter headings.
   Some document classes, like report or book, may have options to control the behavior of page breaks.
   For example, you might use \documentclass[openany]{book} to allow chapters to start on any page, not just on odd-numbered (right-hand) pages.
   latex

   \documentclass[openany]{your_document_class}

   \begin{document}

   % Your document content here

   \appendix

   % Appendix content here

   \end{document}

Remember to replace your_document_class with the actual document class you are using. Experiment with these suggestions to find the approach that works best for your specific document setup.