# LaTeX: remove blank page after a \part or \chapter

Tags: latex

How to remove a blank page that gets added automatically after \part{} or \chapter{} in a book document class?

I need to add some short text describing the \part. Adding some text after the part command results in at least 3 pages with an empty page between the part heading and the text:

1. Part xx
2. (empty)
3. some text

How to get rid of that empty page?

P.S. [Latex: How to remove blank pages coming between two chapters IN Appendix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491904/latex-how-to-remove-blank-pages-coming-between-two-chapters-in-appendix) is similar but it changes the behavior for the rest of the text while I need to remove the empty page for this one \part command only.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A solution that works:

Wrap the part of the document that needs this modified behavior with the code provided below. In my case the portion to wrap is a \part{} and some text following it.

```
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse
\part{Whatever}

Some text

\chapter{Foo}
\@openrighttrue\makeatother
```

The wrapped portion should also include the chapter at the beginning of which this behavior needs to stop. Otherwise LaTeX may generate an empty page before this chapter.

Source: folks at the #latex IRC channel on irc.freenode.net

Comment: ah... i see. was this the first \part command in your document? I tried a variation of my answer above incaed in \makeletter & \makeother in the preamble, and it worked for everything but the first section.

Comment: no, it is the 2nd part of the three. both the 1st and the 3rd part remain as they were, unaffected.

or are you saying that this solution would not work if I needed to modify the 1st \part?

Comment: Brilliant, my "answer of the month" :)

Comment: If I redefine page borders using geometry package it functions, otherwise not.

Comment: how about doing this the other way around? Only have parts starting on the right, and the chapters in there starting wherever (using option openany)

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work for me  :(

Answer (score 72):

I think you can simply add the *oneside* option the book class?

i.e.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
```

Although I didn't test it :)

Comment: I need this modification locally, just for one \part{} statement only.

Comment: where do I add this? Added this at the beginning of my template and this gives an error

Answer (score 52):

It leaves blank pages so that a new part or chapter start on the right-hand side.  You can fix this with the "openany" option for the document class. ;)

Comment: The easiest working and probably best solution to this question. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me as `[oneside]` also changed my headings and margins, while this did not.

Answer (score 11):

You don't say what class you are using, but I'm guessing it is the standard `book`. In which case the page clearing is a feature of he class which you can override as [Mica suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358694/latex-remove-blank-page-after-a-part-or-chapter/1358780#1358780), or solve by switching to another class. The standard `report` class is similar to `book`, or [the `memoir` class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) is an improved `book` and is very flexible indeed.

Comment: not sure if he wants to switch document classes, but i recommend the memoir class as well, i've found it quite easy to control most aspects of the layout with it, the documentation is excellent and goes *very* deep.

Comment: i am cautious of switching document classes as i need to focus on writing right now and not exploring LaTeX. but if switching to memoir is seamless, i might try to do it.

Answer (score 8):

Although I guess you do not need an answer any longer, I am giving the solution for those who will come to see this post.

Derived from book.cls

```
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
              \if@twoside
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \newpage
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
```

It is "\newpage" at the first line of this fragment that adds a redundant blank page after the part header page. So you must redefine the command \@endpart. Add the following snippet to the beggining of your tex file.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@endpart{\vfil
              \if@twoside
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \newpage
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This does not affect my document, something seems to be missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the book class all \part and \chapter are set to start on a recto page.

from book.cls:

```
\newcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
```

you should be able to renew that command, and something similar for the \chapter.

Comment: I tried your suggestion by replacing the \if@openright block with \clearpage (since i know that @openright is not defined) but it did not work - \part{}s after this definition turned into garbage...

Thanks for the suggestion, it seems a good way to go. Could you suggest how to get it working?

Comment: if you have something like \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}, change twoside to oneside. that did it for me, and, someone correct me if i'm wrong, but i believe the only thing that will change other than the \cleardoublepage would be the margins, which is a difference that i've found that nobody cares about.

Comment: That would not answer my question about changing the behavior locally, for one individual instance of \part{} and not for the whole document. However, I have got the solution now. Will post it below.

Answer (score -6):

I know it's a bit late, but I just came across this post and wanted to mention that I don't really see way everybody wants to do it in a difficult way...
The problem here is just that the book class takes twoside as default, so, as gromgull said, just pass oneside as argument and it's solved.

Comment: The question was how to do this for a particular part or chapter, leaving the rest of the document twoside like it was before.